# Querying DBpedia for government office title filter with termStart and termEnd

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

**Goal:** Obtain the DBpedia resource of the person with government office title in certain year. For example President of the United States in 1998, current Mayor of New Haven, Connecticutts, etc...

After looking at the DBpedia resource page for president Barack Obama, mayor Toni Harp and some others, I found that the only consistently provided information are the properties `termStart` and `termEnd`. The problems is that `termStart` and `termEnd` contain multiple entries, and thus using them will also include incorrect resource pages. I do not know how to distinguish the correct from the incorrect.
It seems pretty simple that one should easily obtain result for a query of this nature. It is if one uses `freebase`, but `freebase` is not up to date, so a query for Mayor of New Haven returns empty.

Below is my query for the president of the United States in 1998 using Virtuoso

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?w ?dstart ?dend
WHERE {
    ?s dcterms:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Presidents_of_the_United_States> .
    ?w foaf:primaryTopic ?s .
    ?s prop:termStart ?dstart .
    ?s prop:termEnd ?dend .
    FILTER (?dstart < '1998-01-01'^^xsd:date && ?dend > '1998-12-31'^^xsd:date) .
}
```

The results I got are Barack Obama, Bill Clinton, George W. Bush and William Howard Taft. President Taft was included because of the end date is March 1892, which I think can be fixed. However, I do not know which one of the remaining 3 is the correct one. Bear in mind if I change the Category above, I will get different office titles. For example Mayors_of_New_Haven_,Connecticutts or Governors_of_California etc...

Is there anyway that I can obtain the correct result if only I somehow know the string after the `Category:` is correct but does not know what it is? Or is there anyway to query for any government office title holder at certain date?

Answer (score 2):

In SPARQL:

```
"March 1892"@en > '1998-12-31'^^xsd:date
```

is a comparison error (the value spaces are incompatible) and so the filter is false.

Also - the data looks weird for example: Bill Clinton was president is January 20, 1993 to January 20, 2001 (according to the wikipedia page) yet the results have multiple entries with dstart all over the place.

Comment: DBpedia is a bit flaky right now, but based on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_clinton), I'd guess that it's because Clinton's held multiple offices, each of which has a start and end date.

Comment: I am a completely newbie on the Semantic Web and freebase and DBpedia. I realize the about the date comparison when I see the result, which as I stated above can be fixed. The results seem like a cross join to me. I now see maybe I can use the properties "successor" and/or "predecessor" to get a single result.